# Starting a Thread in object with a parent window

Tags: c++, c, windows, mfc

I have some old MFC code where an object inherits  CDialog

```
class MYCLASS : public CDialog
```

with standard constructor

```
MYCLASS (CWnd* pParent = NULL);
```

each instance of this class is initialised from the main window, and the Overridden Create function creates a modeless dialog

```
BOOL MYCLASS ::Create(CWnd* pParentWnd,long iPort) 
{
    // create the dialogue that I required !
    CDialog::Create(MYCLASS ::IDD, pParentWnd);
    // other stuff....
}
```

Then implements it own WindowProc.

```
LRESULT MYCLASS ::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    // check for our timer event !
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_TIMER :
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case timerPROCESSCOMMS :
            ProcessCommunications();
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This class handles various custom TCPIP communications and the ProcessCommunications has become bigger so i'd like to use a new thread but because of the fact this thread is a child of the main window I'm unsure of how best to start a new thread in this situation.

As I understand it the windowsproc must be implemented in the same thread as the CreateWindow function is called. Now I guess that `CDialog::Create()` must call `CreateWindow()` somewhere along the line so should I start a thread in the constructor?

The threads I've used previously have just either had a Run() function that I have looped while I have needed a task or calculation or just run and exited but I don't know how to deal with this situation where the thread will need not exit but link in with the windows messages.

Comment: Your `CDialog` is going to need to stay in the main thread. It looks like all you need is a message loop and perhaps a message only window. It may be better to implement those directly and avoid MFC.

Comment: will you have multiple dialogs running at the same time, or do you just want to run one dialog while still being able to "do stuff" in the main frame?

Comment: @Robson. Only one dialog is currently running, but as you say stuff is done in the main frame.

Comment: as @serge Ballesta said we need more info about what ProcessCommunications() does, if it can be static or must be non-static, if it does use anything from the MYCLASS, what will it modify etc...

Comment: No it can't be made static unfortunately. Each instance of the class is a separate connection on different ports to different machines with an input and output buffer that are processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a problem of event loop. Your class is a CDialog and a child of the main window. As such, it processes UI events that are delivered in main thread event loop. So `MYCLASS::WindowProc` will always be called in the context of main thread.

You do not give enough details for a precise advice, but I think you are in a classical use case with the main thread dedicated to the handling of UI events (ensuring a responsive UI) and worker threads for back office computing. IMHO, you must implement a communication mechanisme between the UI objects and the TCPIP threads. But some synchronisation on setter methods is often enough.

Comment: The event loop was my concern but was unsure not being a GUI programmer. So setting up some communication between the threads will be no issue. Then I should be create a new thread and create a timer queue with in my new thread to call my     ProcessCommunications() function?

Comment: It hard to say without knowing how `ProcessCommunications()` works, what it uses from `MYCLASS` and how it writes to it. A queue will certainly works (after all it is aimed to threads communication), but may be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

If you make ProcessCommunications a static function it can be executed as a worker thread, like this:

```
AfxBeginThread(ProcessCommunications, this);
```

Comment: I like this, I have not come across    AfxBeginThread() before, but unfortunately     ProcessCommunications() uses data from individual instances of    MYCLASS. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: That is why I suggested passing the instance's this pointer to the thread function. It can be cast to MYCLASS* and used to access the data.  BTW, AfxBeginThread is THE recommended way to start threads when using the MFC library.